# cordova azure media player

Tags: angularjs, cordova, azure, media-player

How would one implement the azureMediaPLayer inside of cordova application?

I tried the tutorials/instructions from the website: http://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/docs/ but I just can't make it work.

I put the

```
<link href="http:////amp.azure.net/libs/amp/1.5.0/skins/amp-default/azuremediaplayer.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src= "http://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/1.5.0/azuremediaplayer.min.js"></script>
```

in my header of index.html

then i put the

```
<video id="vid1" class="azuremediaplayer amp-default-skin" autoplay controls width="640" height="400" poster="poster.jpg" data-setup='{"nativeControlsForTouch": false}'>
    <source src="http://amssamples.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net/91492735-c523-432b-ba01-faba6c2206a2/AzureMediaServicesPromo.ism/manifest" type="application/vnd.ms-sstr+xml" />
    <p class="amp-no-js">
        To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that supports HTML5 video
    </p>
</video>
```

in the html

and it's just a black screen, no controls, no loading, and no error message from debug.

I tried the manual example running from the angular controller but that just tells me that amp is undefined.

```
var myPlayer = amp('vid1', { /* Options */
        "nativeControlsForTouch": false,
        autoplay: false,
        controls: true,
        width: "640",
        height: "400",
        poster: ""
    }, function() {
          console.log('Good to go!');
           // add an event listener
          this.addEventListener('ended', function() {
            console.log('Finished!');
        }
      }
);
myPlayer.src([{ 
    src: "http://amssamples.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net/91492735-c523-432b-ba01-faba6c2206a2/AzureMediaServicesPromo.ism/manifest", 
    type: "application/vnd.ms-sstr+xml"
}]);
```

Have anyone made this work? I started to look into the dash.js but I can't make that work either...

Comment: correction to the error result: it's black screen as in content not loaded to video element, controls are visible but it's the default html5 controls so something is telling me the azure stuff isn't loaded properly...

Answer (score 2):

Cordova has the concept of whitelisting domains that are okay for use in the application.  You will need to whitelist the domains for the AMP scripts and your domain for the streaming locators.  Here is more information: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/appdev/whitelist/index.html